# setTimeout и ручная перезагрузка страницы

Tags: javascript

У меня появилась непростая для меня задача, есть

```
// time это количество секунд
setTimeout(function(){
    // тут что-то
    location.reload();
}, time * 1000);
```

после загрузки страницы таймер начинает отсчет, но если перезагрузить страницу вручную, таймер начнет отсчет заново.

Можно ли этого как-то избежать?

Comment: что а таймер вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy `time * 1000` время после которого страница перезагрузится

Comment: то есть вы хотите перезагружать в какое-то определенное время? к тому же вы никак не можете отличить первую загрузку от перезагрузки по f5 например

Comment: Можете сохранять пройденное время и начинать потом отчет с него

Comment: @ZhukovRoman я не представляю как это сделать

Comment: @donttime а вот эта переменная `time` откуда берется? Вы её сами в файле javascript будете устанавливать или с сервера будет прилетать настройка?

Comment: @donttime а еще хотелось узнать с какой целью используется одноразовая перезагрузка страницы? Т.к. возможны другие решения  проблемы.

Answer (score 5):

Сохраняйте значение таймера в [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), и считывайте его или инициализируйте при необходимости при загрузке. Таким образом, если страница перезагрузится, таймер начнет отсчет с того момента, когда страница была перезагружена, а не с нуля.

Comment: так это придётся каждую секунду записывать в store

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? LocalStorage достаточно производителен для записи каждую секунду.

Comment: в коде из вопроса _один_ `setTimeout`, которому устанавливается задержка. вы предлагаете добавить еще `setInterval` чтобы записывать каждую секунду например?

Comment: допустим количество прошедших секунд можно считать в том же setTimeout, а в localStorage записывать при выполнении события window.onbeforeunload

Comment: @EnverDzhaparoff `onbeforeunload ` не везде работает. Оно к сожалению не универсально(

Comment: @EnverDzhaparoff, вы **не можете** считать что-то _в том же setTimeout_ так как функция переданная setTimeout выполнится один раз по истечении таймаута

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский [описание на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) - проблемы могут быть только с мобильными браузерами

Comment: @EnverDzhaparoff к сожалению это не так. ...а мобильные браузеры.....вы забываете в какой век мы живем....

Comment: @Grundy - согласен, ступил. Можно создавать временные метки, используя `Date.now()` в момент инициализации и в момент перезагрузки, и если число секунд будет меньше заданного, сохранять значение в хранилище. Правда, в этом случае придется использовать все тот же `onbeforeunload `

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский инфа из [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) тоже достаточно оптимистична.

Answer (score 1):

Перед первой перезагрузкой устанавливайте куку-признак того, что перезагрузка уже была вызвана. Перед закрытием окна/уходом со страницы удаляйте куку, чтобы избежать путаницы при повторном заходе пользователя на страницу

Comment: а как вы отличите перезагрузку по f5(ручную) от `location.reload();`?

Comment: @Grundy следить за нажатием клавиш? если не ошибаюсь, у F5 код 116

Comment: @alenkins в вы можете отследить нажатие на стрелочку перезагрузки страницы в браузере?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно инкрементировать в cookie количество загрузок страницы до ухода с сайта (перед которым всё обнулять). Если оно будет больше `стартовое значение + 1` - не выполнять перезагрузку по таймауту.

Comment: @alenkins, так в вопросе как раз про таймер было, фактически чтобы он не прерывался, а при каждой перезагрузке он будет сначала начинаться и нельзя отличить нужная это перезагрузка или не нужная

Comment: @Grundy то есть цель - возобновить отсчёт с момента первой загрузки страницы? если, опять же, проверять наличие куки с меткой времени и в случае её отсутствия записывать туда текущее время и для setTimeout устанавливать полный интервал ожидания. Если метка времени уже существует, то выставлять в таймаут ожидание с корректировкой по разнице между текущим временем и записанным в куке.

Comment: @alenkins, ну вы в принципе не можете отличить первую загрузку от перезагрузки обычной

Comment: @Grundy во время первой загрузки кука не существует (удалять её beforeunload), почему не использовать это как признак?

Comment: потому что куки могут отсутствовать по различным причинам, иногда они даже могут быть запрещены